# Difference in meaning? "Would" vs "shall"

Tags: will-shall, will-would

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> What **would** we crime reporters do without juicy murders?
>
> What **shall** we crime reporters do without juicy murders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What *would* we crime reporters do without juicy murders?

is posing a *hypothetical* question about a *possibility* in the future.

> What shall we crime reporters do without juicy murders?

is asking about an event which will happen with *certainty* in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> What shall we crime reporters do without juicy murders?

This sentence implies that suddenly all juicy murders had stopped, and the crime reporters are legitimately debating what to do. Shall implies the future, not present.

> What would we crime reporters do without juicy murders?

This sentence is more natural, and is most likely the usage you're thinking of.